# Show $\langle u,v \rangle = u_1v_1+3u_2v_2$ is an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I understand for a vector space to be an inner product it must meet four properties:

1. $\langle u+v,w \rangle =\langle u,w \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$.
2. $\langle \alpha v,w \rangle = \alpha \langle v,w \rangle$
3. $\langle u , v \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle $.
4. $\langle v,v \rangle \geq 0 $ with equality iff $v=0$.

   But I'm not sure how I can go about proving the above equation as an inner product.

Comment: Hi Erebus, have you considered checking these four properties directly?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to input into the statement, but I'm still new to the formatting and so it's not showing up.

Comment: No, like have you checked it mathematically

Comment: I'll do it for you. In the meantime, can I suggest you simply go ahead and verify the four conditions? It really is that simple! :)

Comment: Erebus, do you understand what Kenny Wong is saying? I remember it was not obvious to me what to do in these situations either when I was learning these things.

Comment: Thanks Kenny. Yes, these properties consist of the communicative, distributive, communicative, and the orthogonal property.

Comment: So would I have to go through use the given equations and go through each property? If I can prove that all four are correct, then it is an inner product. If one statement is false, then it is not?

Comment: That's right! It's just a brute force calculation.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks Kenny. I appreciate it. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I guess, what confuses me is that the properties apply to a vector with three elements, but I'm only working with two. That's why it's hard to see it right away. How would you apply the principles to just two elements in a vector?

Answer (score 0):

1. $\langle u+v,w \rangle = (u_1+v_1)w_1+3(u_2+v_2)w_2 = (u_1 w_1 +3u_2 w_2)+ (v_1 w_1 +3v_2 w_2)\\
   =\langle u,w \rangle + \langle v,w \rangle$
2. $ \langle \alpha v,w \rangle = (\alpha v_1) w_1 +3(\alpha v_2) w_2 = \alpha (v_1 w_1 +3v_2 w_2) =\alpha \langle  v,w \rangle$

The rest is that easy, just expand and distribute ;)

Comment: I see how it is. Got it. Thanks :) What confuses me is that the w is written in the properties, but I was only given u and v. Just adding the w won't change the equation and makes it easier to see. Thanks. .