# Is $\langle u,v\rangle $ $=$ $4x_1y_1 - 6x_1y_2 - 6x_2y_1 + 11x_2y_2$ an inner product in $\mathbb R ^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I already know that $\langle u,v\rangle$ is already in the form of $x^T$$Ay$, but I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Should the value of $A$ suppose to be the same?

Comment: Do you know what you need to check in order to decide whether it is an inner product?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "should the $A$ suppose to be the same".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think that the value of A must be the same value for all xy terms.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716970/intuition-for-inner-product-defined-with-matrix

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2261516/265466 for direct verification of the properties an inner product must have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already note that the expression can be written as
$$\Big \langle \dbinom{x_1}{x_2},\dbinom{y_1}{y_2} \Big \rangle 
= \big( x_1 \ \ x_2) \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -6 \\ -6 & 11 \end{pmatrix} \dbinom{y_1}{y_2} \tag{1}$$
or more compact, $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \rangle = \mathbf{x}^tA\mathbf{y}$, where $A$ is the above matrix, the linearity in the first entry is easy to prove.

Also, since $A$ is symmetric, and $\mathbf{x}^tA\mathbf{y}$ is equal to its own transpose (since it is a scalar) it follows that
$$\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \rangle = \mathbf{x}^tA\mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{x}^tA\mathbf{y})^t = \mathbf{y}^tA^t\mathbf{x} = \langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{x} \rangle.$$

Finally, we need to prove that $\langle X,X \rangle > 0$ for $X \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\mathbf0\}$, or equivalently, we need to verify that $\langle X,X \rangle \geq 0$ for all $X \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and the equality only when $X = \mathbf0$. I think is more easy to check the second. So, let
$$X = \dbinom{x}{y} \mathbb{R}^2$$
and then

\begin{align}
\langle X,X \rangle 
&= 4x^2 - 12xy + 11y^2 \\
&= (2x-3y)^2 + 2y^2.
\end{align}
Now, it is easy to see that $\langle X,X \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle X,X \rangle = 0$ only when $2x-3y=0$ and $y=0$, that is, only when $X$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\langle x,y \rangle = x^TAy$ is an inner product
iff $A$ is symmetric and positive definite
iff $A$ is symmetric and has positive eigenvalues.